# Sortable Unordered list serialize it then convert to table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm able to get the serialzed data of a sortable UL

HTML

```
<ul id="ul_1">
<li id="A_1">200></li>
<li id="A_2">300></li>
<li id="A_3">150></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
  $("#cmdSerial").click(function (event) {

                event.preventDefault();
                var data = $("#ul_1").sortable('serialize');
                alert(data);
            });
```

from the ul I would need to get a table like this

```
id |Values
A_1|200
A_2|300  
A_3|150
```

I thought that by serializing I could get the data but var data shows as

```
A[]=1&A[]=2&A[]=3
```

Edit. From this post I was able to get the following which solves my problem.

```
 $("#cmdSerial").click(function (event) {

                event.preventDefault();
                //create array with object. 
               var dataArray = $.map($("#formgroup_ul_1").children('li'), function (el) {
                    return { 'color': $(el).data('cube'), 'group': $(el).data('group') };

                });
               //loop array
               for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                   console.log(dataArray[i].color + ' ' + dataArray[i].group);

                   $('#mDataTable tbody').append('<tr><td>' + dataArray[i].color + ' ' + dataArray[i].group + '</td></tr>');

               }
   });
```

Comment: Could you post some more code - the HTML and/or Javascript?  I would like to know what `myul` looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use sortable's **[toArray](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray)** method.

Such that:

```
var myArray = $("#ul_1").sortable('toArray');
//=> ["A_1", "A_2", "A_3"]
```

Comment: Thank you but it looks like this methods only give you the order and id of the items correct? is there a way I can specifi other values? for example data-value?

Comment: Yes the default is `id` but you can change it via an object with `attribute: 'someAttr'`